# DAX measure to output percentile rank within columns of a table

Tags: powerbi, dax, ranking

I am trying to create a measure that will give the percentile rank within multiple columns of rent data that I have. For each property agent and within each block and property type I would like to rank the rent received. I intend to use this ranking to create conditional formatting so that the relatively low rents can be seen visually when looking at the data in a matrix.

I tried to do this with RANKX and EARLIER but it doesn't seem to work in measure - can anyone help? I have attached a sample of the data to this post:

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgouikQ3N5U5ghTO03180W5kRhOw?e=4lMCG6

I tried using RANKX with EARLIER but it did not work.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Hello , you have more chance of getting some help if you provide sample data (10-20 lines) with expected result